# probability distributions over intersecting sets

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

1. Let's say I have two probability distributions over two intersecting sets of possible things; e.g. sets {A,B,C,D} and {C,D,E,F} with respective probabilities {.1,.3,.4,.2} and {.2,.4,.3,.1}. Assume that C and D refer to the same entity in both sets. Is there a productive way of thinking about the relation between these two distributions? E.g., how are {A,B} and {E,F} related?
2. More complex case, but closer to my actual problem: I have two probability distributions over intersecting state spaces. One space is the set of possible (binary) states of {A,B,C,D} ({0,0,0,0},{1,0,0,0}, etc.), the other is the set of possible states of {C,D,E,F}. Again, C and D are the same entity. If I have the probability of each state, given one or the other space, is there a meaningful way of thinking about the intersection of the two distributions?
3. Still more complex (and closer), imagine that the probabilities in 2) are conditional on other states that might not be included in the described sets. So marginalizing over A,B and E,F won't necessarily give you the same thing over C,D.

I can explain in more detail if unclear. I appreciate any feedback, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The (elementary) events $A,B,C,D,E,F$ cannot be defined on the same probability space with the given probabilities as conditional probabilities. Let $O=\{A,B,C,D\}$ and $O'=\{C,D,E,F\}$ with the probabilities $$P(O),P(O')>0$$ and we need the following conditional probabilities:

$$P(\{C\}\mid O)=\frac {P(\{C\})}{P(O)}=0.4, \ P(\{D\}\mid O)=\frac {P(\{D\})}{P(O)}=0.2$$
and at the same time we also need

$$P(\{C\}\mid O')=\frac {P(\{C\})}{P(O')}=0.2, \ P(\{D\}\mid O')=\frac {P(\{D\})}{P(O')}=0.4. $$

The point is that $P(O')=2P(O)$ in order to get the left equality above and $P(O')=\frac12P(O)$ in order to get the right hand side equality above. This is impossible.

Comment: Ah, I can see this. But the values I used were made up on the spot, supposing that they *are* consistent, where can I look for relations between the two distributions, based on their intersection?

Or are you suggesting that, more generally, there can be no meaningful relation if the distributions are inconsistent as you describe (which I think can still be true in my case, if the conditional is different for the two sets)?